# What is the use of firebase-messaging-sw.js in firebase web notifications?

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have configured Javascript API for firebase push notifications on my website. Everything is working fine but I'm seeing many 'Background messages'. I've just put the **firebase-messaging-sw.js** file in my website's directory.

I don't know the use of it. I was just trying to know what it does. If you see following code, you'll see I haven't provided the `messagingSenderId` still this file gets executed.

So what I want to know is:

How it works without ID?

What is the use of it? Is it a mandatory file to receive push notifications and handle them in `onMessage` handler?

Where should I actually put this file (my current directory is: **MY-SITE-DOMAIN/firebase-messaging-sw.js** but the firebase notifications are configured in different directory)?

Here's the code:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': 'YOUR-SENDER-ID'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
 console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
 const notificationTitle = 'Background Message from html';
  const notificationOptions = {
   body: 'Background Message body.',
   icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
 };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
     notificationOptions);
});
```

Original file is [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/messaging/firebase-messaging-sw.js)

Comment: importscripts not working in my app why :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the configuration below or just the messagingSenderID. 
You may have setup the config in your other javascript due to which it is not throwing any error.

```
var config = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: ""
    };
```

firebase-messaging-sw.js is a must and should be present in the host root directory. This is required to setup background notification handler when browser is not in focus or in background.

Comment: Is there any link/source to confirm `firebase-messaging-sw.js should be present in the host root directory`?

Comment: @NimitBhargava: here you go: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token - second paragraph `create an empty file with that name and place it in the root of your domain before retrieving a token`

Comment: @quetzalcoatl if we use `navigator.serviceWorker.register('/scripts/service-worker.js')` Only requests that start with `/script/` will go through the ServiceWorker and the rest will not.
Source: https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/register-sw

Answer (score 9):

By default firebase will be looking for /firebase-messaging-sw.js which should contain the firebase libraries and listeners. More details here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive

If you would like to use an existing service worker, you can use https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging#useServiceWorker

like this...

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(registration => {
  firebase.messaging().useServiceWorker(registration)
})
```

Comment: in the current firebase (v9) the registered service worker can be passed to the `getToken` method from `firebase/messaging` under the `serviceWorkerRegistration` option. see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/messaging_.gettokenoptions

Answer (score 4):

Create empty file `firebase-messaging-sw.js` at root of project.

Comment: The question is WHAT is the use but not WHERE to create
Original question: `What is the use of firebase-messaging-sw.js in firebase web notifications?`

Answer (score 0):

In Apache Tomcat create at /usr/share/apache-tomcat-9.0.30/webapps/ROOT

Comment: The question is is WHAT is the use but not WHERE to create
Original question: `What is the use of firebase-messaging-sw.js in firebase web notifications?`

Answer (score 0):

The point of that firebase-messaging-sw file is to set up a service worker that firebase will add to the clients browser. The service worker will listen for push events to it. If the service worker is active and running, while being in the background, if it receives a new push event, it will process the code registered in it, and that will eventually turn into the push notification that the user will see.

The absolute best resource I know of to learn more about the general process of implementing push notifications is this: https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/

Anyone read that and they will know the steps to making push notifications and the abstractions of firebase will also make sense as well. As far as I can tell.